# "The email address is not a valid email address" for a working SE login

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, stack-exchange-openid

With the new login form on all the StackExchange sites (not sure when this changed, I don't see the login form all that often), I am not allowed to log in using my StackExchange account anymore.

When I fill in my SE account email address and password in the "Email" and "Password" fields respectively I get the message "The email address is not a valid email address." as the response.
It is however my (valid) email address that I entered; it has no funny characters in it or anything like that, only thing that possibly stands out is that it's rather short (like x@xx.xx).

However, if I instead select "more login options" and then enter "https://openid.stackexchange.com" in the "OpenID" field I get sent to a different login form which accepts the exact same credentials.

Am I misunderstanding the login form somehow or is this just a straight-up bug?

Edit: It turns out that expanding the "more login options" portion of the login form was the way to trigger the problem.

Comment: Make sure there are no trailing spaces when you enter your email. The form is a bit... particular about that at the moment. It's also possible that I broke the form at some point. Can you walk me through what you do to log in? Do you just straight up go to type in your email or do you end up selecting another provider or clicking "more login options" first? Do you hit enter to log in, or actually click the button?  Do you get the error after submitting the form or while you're still typing your credentials in? What browser are you using?

Comment: @AnnaLear This was in Chrome 45.0.2454.101. I think I just figured out the specifics of the problem when trying to retrace my steps in order to answer your questions. I think that I must have already expanded the "advanced" bit of the form (being used to clicking a "log in using stackexchange" button in the old form) and at that point the "Login" button no longer works.

Comment: Aha, that'd be my bad, then. Will fix next week. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you for your quick help!  I didn't realise that expanding the advanced portion of the form was the way to trigger the problem until I first failed to reproduce the problem while answering you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be fixed as of about 20 minutes ago. (Fun fact: past me decided to use *two* forms on that page. Why? Nobody knows.)

Holler at me if you still see any weirdness.